# Socket.io and Keystone - Reference socket.io object

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, keystonejs

I am trying to integrate socket.io into my keystone app. I am instantiating the object in the bottom of my keystone.app like so:

```
var sock = require('socket.io'); 

keystone.start({
        onStart: function() {

            var hserver = keystone.httpServer;                 
            var io = keystone.set('io', sock.listen(hserver)).get('io');

            // Socket function
            io.on('connection', function (socket) {
                console.log('Socket connected.')

                socket.on('hon', function (data) {
                    socket.emit('hon_res', {data})
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

This all works fine and I am able to emit and recieve messages from my sockets. The problem arrises when I am trying to emit a message after one of my models is used to insert data into mongo db.

Inside my schema/model file. I have added this portion. It is being called correctly, but the socket seems unable to connect to the socket session.

```
Hon.schema.post('save', function(data){
    var io = keystone.get('io');
    io.attach(keystone.httpServer)

    io.sockets.emit('hon_upd');
});
```

I recieve this error in the client console, a few seconds after the post save function is called:

```
VM7414 extensions::messaging:79 Uncaught Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
    at PortImpl.postMessage (extensions::messaging:79:13)
    at Port.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as postMessage] (extensions::utils:149:26)
    at destroyPurpleBox (file:///Users/thobyy/Library/Application%20Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/7.2.2_0/dist/purplebox.js:43:9)
    at file:///Users/thobyy/Library/Application%20Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij/7.2.2_0/dist/purplebox.js:51:5
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you attaching io to httpserver once agait.

```
io.attach(keystone.httpServer)
```

try removing above line